# How to decrease varchar of MySQL column which exists value with Rails migration?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to migrate table column length 255 to 191 to change characterset from utf8 to utf8mb4.

Rails migration is below.

```
  def self.up
    change_column :friend_user_lists, :comment, :string, :limit => 191
  end
```

I already changed database, table and column charset to utf8mb4, and got an error below.

```
Mysql::Error: Data truncated for column 'comment' at row 118: ALTER TABLE `friend_user_lists` CHANGE `comment` `comment` varchar(191) DEFAULT NULL
```

I guess that the error shows that too much long values exist.
Then how to migrate?

Comment: If truncation is not a problem to you, create a rake task to truncate the values in this field first, run this rake task and then run the migration.

Comment: It's not a problem but it seems better to write in migration file since it's just for once.

Answer (score 4):

If you're ok to truncate existing comment records then I'd just do it in the migration:

```
def self.up
  FriendUserList.where('LENGTH(comment) > 191').each { |r| r.update(comment: r.comment[0...191]) }
  change_column :friend_user_lists, :comment, :string, :limit => 191
end
```